# Obtaining output of php file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file stored remotely.  It uses post to take 2 variables, "username" and "password", which will then echo either Valid or Invalid depending on it's existence in my database.  I currently use this with my android application to log users in.

I would like to use this same script for logging into my website that I am building.  I need to be able to pass 2 variables that I have obtained from an HTML form to a javascript function which will take the variables, run them though the php query, read the echoed output and decide to return true or false to the form.  Below is the code I currently have for the script

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Login(){
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            if (username == "" || password == "") {
                alert ("Please fill in username and password fields");
                return false;
            }
            $.post("my_query_url.php",{username:username, password:password}, function(data) {
                if (data.toLowerCase == "valid")
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            });
        }
    </script>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="Main.html" method="post" onsubmit=" return Login();"> 
    Username: <br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
    Password: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Currently, it always sends the user to my Main.html page with any non-empty username/password input.

I'm not very well versed in these two languages, but I need to learn quickly as they are important for my Senior Project class semester, and especially these next two weeks.  Is this possible to do with Javascript and HTML only?  Some pointers will be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: You should use Ajax to send request to server and get output.

Comment: browser submits to `main.html` ,when you click `submit`

Comment: @justanothercoder .he is using ajax.`$.post`

Comment: Am I wrong that `toLowerCase` is a function so it should be called like `if ( data.toLowerCase() == "valid" )` You are comapring function to string.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that justanothercoder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually are almost all the way there.  You just need to return false from your Login function to prevent the default action of the form from triggering (which is to redirect to main.html).  Then, instead of relying on the form to redirect the user, you will need to do so yourself via javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Login(){
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        if (username == "" || password == "") {
            alert ("Please fill in username and password fields");
            return false;
        }
        $.post("my_query_url.php",{username:username, password:password}, function(data) {
            if (data.toLowerCase() === "valid")
                window.location.href = "./Main.html"; //redirect the user
            else 
                return false;
        });
        return false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey runspired.  I added your changes and removed the action from my form.  Now what I am getting is that no action happens on both correct and incorrect login credentials.  Any more tips?  As I said before, I'm not very well versed in these languages.  Is there any way I can be sure that the 'data' variable is actually getting anything from the php script?

Comment: did you miss the redirect change?

Comment: I added that to the code, so I'm thinking that it's not reaching the php query correctly, or that 'data' doesn't hold what I think it should have

Comment: add `console.log(data);` at the top of the callback to see what it is, or if you are using Chrome, right click inspect element, click on "network" and try the request again.

Comment: You can inspect the server response thoroughly from there.

Comment: @justanothercoder's observation is also correct, the String.toLowerCase should be a function.

Comment: I keep getting this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load my_query.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
I think that you've solved one problem but I've got another to handle.

Comment: Ok, after uploading the pages to my server, I was able to get around that XMLHttpRequest error, and the code is working!  Thank you very much for your help!